# Python Decorator to Cast Class Attributes for MyPy

Tags: python, mypy, python-decorators, python-typing

I have a class that has multiple methods that can only be called if an attribute that may be `None` is not `None`. E.g.

```py
class Connection:
    def read(self) -> str:
        return "data"
    
    def write(self, data: str) -> None:
        print(data)
    

class Foo:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._connection: None | Connection = None
        
    def connect(self):
        self._connection = Connection()
        
        
    def get_data(self) -> str:
        if self._connection is None:
            raise RuntimeError()
        else:
            return self._connection.read()
        
    def send_data(self, data: str):
        if self._connection is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Connection not created")
        else:
            self._connection.write(data)
```

If I run `mypy` on the code above it has no issues.

However, instead of manually checking inside each method that the connection has been created, I'd rather just have a decorator that checks if the connection has been created before entering the method.

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import cast

class Connection:
    def read(self) -> str:
        return "data"
    
    def write(self, data: str) -> None:
        print(data)
    

def requires_connection(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._connection is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Connection not created")
        else:
            cast(Connection, self._connection)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator    
    
    
class Foo:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._connection: None | Connection = None
        
    def connect(self):
        self._connection = Connection()
        
        
    @requires_connection
    def get_data(self) -> str:
        return self._connection.read()
        
    @requires_connection
    def send_data(self, data: str):
        self._connection.write(data)
```

This code does what I want, in the sense that it raises an error if I try to call `get_data` or `send_data` before the connection has been created. But if I try to check my code with `mypy`, it doesn't recognise that the `_connection` attribute is not `None`.

```
error: Item "None" of "Connection | None" has no attribute "read"  [union-attr]
error: Item "None" of "Connection | None" has no attribute "write"  [union-attr]
```

Is there a way to centralize the logic of making sure that `_connection` is not `None` in a way that `mypy` will recognise?

Comment: It'd be much better to accept a connection as an argument instead of initializing it to None.

Comment: But if you must do it this way (you don't) then make a `def connection` property which does the logic and always returns a connection